# Bootstrap and css are both not working correctly in django project

Tags: python, html, css, django, python-3.x

I am using a html5 theme (https://colorlib.com/preview/theme/personal/) in my django 2 project. But, It's style not working correctly. I have linked all css correctly. My Django Project link (https://github.com/shahriar-programmer/personal-django).

My Html code

https://github.com/shahriar-programmer/personal-django/blob/master/templates/index.html

I need this type of view:

[Actual Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBy4f.png)

But My App's look is

[My App result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptyc4.png)

How can I modify my code to make it properly stylish like the theme preview?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! for us to better answer your question can you please attach the screenshot of your app output and also the snippet of css code where you are having trouble

Comment: @NishantPatel Sir, I have updated my question. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have cloned your code and run on my local, its working fine for me. So it's not a code issue.
from my experience i would suggest you, you can try below few things:-

1:- Try rerun you django server.
2:- Try doing a hard refresh of your page on browser.

Comment: I have rerun my server and also I have used different browser but it is giving me same result. :(

Comment: The app should look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBy4f.png

Comment: Solve!! I have cleaned my browser cache and the problem solved. Thanks to @Gaurank Goyal..